# php ini_set and ini_get isnt working the way I want

Tags: php, get, set, ini

Im using this

```
    ini_set('post_max_size','40M');
echo ini_get('post_max_size');
```

And for some reason post_max_size is echoing out 8M (the default one) and not 40M.
Is the

Comment: some values may be locked by you're hostin provider , so you can't change all of them .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `post_max_size` isn't settable at runtime. PHP only runs after the file has been uploaded, you can't use the `ini_set` until the `upload_max_filesize` has been determined. So, you can't use `ini_set` to set the setting for that reason.

You will have to set this option directly from `php.ini`.

[See the docs for more info](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: when @Sarfaz say php.ini it could be as well your apache virtualhost configuration (or .htaccess) with php_value or php_admin_value commands (and you'll see that with php_admin_value the setting cannot be changed in the PHP script)

Answer (score 1):

[post_max_size](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) is a INI directive that can be changed PHP_INI_PERDIR only, as stated [in the manual](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Again, [from the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php):

> PHP_INI_PERDIR : Entry can be set in
>   php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf